# Delete but not cut a line in Vim

Tags: vim

This is not duplicate of [delete line in vi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11369/delete-line-in-vi), it's asking different question. I'd like to delete a line without cutting it (placing it in clipboard).

I'd like to copy part of line, delete a line and then paste just that part of line somewhere else. Using `v3w`, `dd` and then `p` pastes whole line.

Comment: This question is conflating the _unnamed register_ in VIM with an X11 _clipboard selection_, accessible in VIM via a _selection register_.

Comment: @JdeBP for advanced VI user it might be conflicting because we have knowledge of Vi, but for novice it makes sense as he is not aware of both neither named nor unnamed registers in Vi; but pointing from here to those questions might be good addition, if you have exact links feel free to add to my answer.

Comment: "those questions" has no antecedent.  I did not talk about any other questions than this one.

Comment: Now that the subject of other questions has been raised by someone else, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7788/ from 7 years ago.

Comment: why not: `v3w "_dd p` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the **black hole register** ([`:help quote_`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote_)). If you prepend `"_` to a delete command, the contents will just be gone. So, to delete and keep the next three words, and then get rid of the entire line, you'd use `d3w"_dd`.

#### Advanced mapping

That use case of keeping a part of the line while removing the complete line is a common one; I've written a set of mappings for that:

```
"["x]dDD            Delete the characters under the cursor until the end
"                   of the line and [count]-1 more lines [into register x],
"                   and delete the remainder of the line (i.e. the
"                   characters before the cursor) and possibly following
"                   empty line(s) without affecting a register.
"["x]dD{motion}     Delete text that {motion} moves over [into register x]
"                   and delete the remainder of the line(s) and possibly
"                   following empty line(s) without affecting a register.
"{Visual}["x],dD    Delete the highlighted text [into register x] and delete
"                   the remainder of the selected line(s) and possibly
"                   following empty line(s) without affecting a register.
function! s:DeleteCurrentAndFollowingEmptyLines()
    let l:currentLnum = line('.')
    let l:cnt = 1
    while l:currentLnum + l:cnt < line('$') && getline(l:currentLnum + l:cnt) =~# '^\s*$'
        let l:cnt += 1
    endwhile

    return '"_' . l:cnt . 'dd'
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <SID>(DeleteCurrentAndFollowingEmptyLines) <SID>DeleteCurrentAndFollowingEmptyLines()
nnoremap <script> dDD D<SID>(DeleteCurrentAndFollowingEmptyLines)
xnoremap <script> ,dD d<SID>(DeleteCurrentAndFollowingEmptyLines)
function! s:DeleteCurrentAndFollowingEmptyLinesOperatorExpression()
    set opfunc=DeleteCurrentAndFollowingEmptyLinesOperator
    let l:keys = 'g@'

    if ! &l:modifiable || &l:readonly
        " Probe for "Cannot make changes" error and readonly warning via a no-op
        " dummy modification.
        " In the case of a nomodifiable buffer, Vim will abort the normal mode
        " command chain, discard the g@, and thus not invoke the operatorfunc.
        let l:keys = ":call setline('.', getline('.'))\<CR>" . l:keys
    endif

    return l:keys
endfunction
function! DeleteCurrentAndFollowingEmptyLinesOperator( type )
    try
        " Note: Need to use an "inclusive" selection to make `] include the last
        " moved-over character.
        let l:save_selection = &selection
        set selection=inclusive

        execute 'silent normal! g`[' . (a:type ==# 'line' ? 'V' : 'v') . 'g`]"' . v:register . 'y'

        execute 'normal!' s:DeleteCurrentAndFollowingEmptyLines()
    finally
        if exists('l:save_selection')
            let &selection = l:save_selection
        endif
    endtry
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> dD <SID>DeleteCurrentAndFollowingEmptyLinesOperatorExpression()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can copy that part that you want to use in named buffer and paste from there, for example:

```
"ay3w
```

this will yank 3 words in named buffer a
and

```
"ap
```

would paste from named buffer a later; also you could first delete 3 words and then delete all line and later paste with

```
"2p
```

this would paste 2nd from last deletion from deletion buffer;
also following suggestions on comments as this is VIM tagged question - there is native VIM solution for this (does not work on Vi):

```
y3w then in new place "0p
```

VIM has native feature to keep last yank in 0 registry.

Comment: Why not use VIM's _black hole register_?

Comment: @JdeBP are you serious? Did you even read the answer - second option in my answer is exactly that  - I only did not name it black hole register - some what old style naming - deletion registry but essentially same thing numbered buffer from 1-9 keeping track of last changes in file

Comment: The second option in your answer _is not_ the black hole register.  The black hole register is not a numbered register.

Comment: @JdeBP read here: http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2010/06/vims-black-hole-register.html it seems that I have had partially wrong assumption that it the same, but essentially it's same with expanded functionality, that definitely is not needed here; also I try to stick to vi not vim features as often working on systems where vim is not available; but admit that it's not exactly the same - sorry for my bad comment

Comment: I don't need to read that, as I already know about the black hole register, and that it _is not_ essentially the same as a numbered register, it being essentially _different_ in fact.  I've given you a suggestion for making your answer better, to a question that definitely _is_ about VIM, labelled as such in both tags and title.  You've refused it.  Don't be dismayed then if someone else comes along, reads my suggestion, and posts an answer giving the simple black hole register way of doing this that has no extra side-effects.  I gave you the opportunity to make a good comprehensive answer.

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks, I just don't see how using black hole here would improve solution in this use case, specially the second, where by the way additionally instead of deleting and pasting from register 2, in VIM could y3w and "0p - that would be VIM feature to use here - that last yank is put in 0 register so no complex solution necessary.

Comment: The difference is that pasting from the black hole register returns nothing. Using any of the other named registers will. The black hole register is where you put stuff of you don't want it affect later pasting at all.

Comment: That's clear @muru but I still don't see big value of that, because when I want to keep something I put it in named register, deletion go auto in numbered, also I often work with vi on solaris, hp-ux where sometimes even have version of vi where moving around cursor can't be done with arrows, so I personally try not to become too addicted to new specific use-case features that does not give clear benefit - because I don't see real benefit from not saving my deletion - even opposite I like to be able to revert my error from numbered register; but agree - it can be useful in specific use-cases.